# SQLITE update command with multiple condition does not work

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Update command does not work for multiple condition.

```
public int updateDayCycle(DailyView dailyView, String date, String time) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ACTIVITY, dailyView.getActivity());
        Log.i("KEY_ACTIVITY", dailyView.getActivity());
        Log.i("DATETIME",date+" "+time);
        return db.update(TABLE_DAY_CYCLE_DETAILS, values, KEY_DATE + " = ? AND " +
                KEY_TIMING + " = ?", new String[]{date, time});
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error in logcat?

Comment: i didn't get any error but it's not updating

Comment: Did it return any value ? What is `dailyView.getActivity()` display

Comment: I assume you validated that the date & time are valid and correct in formatting?